# What's a good approximation to this combinatorics problem?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have $k$ groups $g_1, g_2, ..., g_k$ of sizes $n_1, n_2, ..., n_k$, with $\sum_{i=1}^k n_i = n$ such that $n$ is divisible by 2. We wish to pair every member with a member of a different group. What is the probability a member of $g_i$ is paired with a member of $g_j$?

For example, if $k = 3$, and we have group sizes $n_1 = 1, n_2 = 1$, and $n_3 = 2$, then the only possible solution pairs the members of groups 1 and 2 with a member of group 3. Hence the probabilities are:

- a member of $g_1$ is paired with a member of $g_2$ with probability 0, $g_3$ with probability 1.
- a member of $g_2$ is paired with a member of $g_1$ with probability 0, $g_3$ probability 1.
- a member of $g_3$ is paired with a member of $g_1$ with probability 1/2, $g_2$ with probability 1/2.

We get the same results with $n_1 = 1000, n_2 = 1000, n_3 = 2000$, etc.

I want to find a good approximation for these probabilities for large $n$, and for different values of $k$ up to around $10$.

I have considered evaluating the problem with the inclusion exclusion principle, but counting gets difficult for large $n_i$, and I wish to evaluate this probability computationally, so am limited in the number of factorials I can use.

Thanks!

Comment: so we assume all persons are distinct and every correct pairing has same likelyhood ?

Comment: @Asinomás yes, each member of each group is part of exactly one pairing, and each set of correct pairings are equally likely.